# Can a PI controller be designed by pole placement in the z-plane without transforming the system equations to the state space?

Tags: pid-controller, z-transform

I've some time trying to design a PI controller by pole placement for a BLDC motor, I had basically to study control engineering from zero because I had several years without doing nothing of control systems.

Recently I completed the design of my PI controller on the s-plane and when the final equations are plotted then it works in the expected way. The problem came when the resulting equations where transformed to the z-plane, then the behavior wasn't good. I took the advice of one professor and started the design again to do it entirely in the z-plane.

I've been reading the discrete Ogata, and in that book the pole placement method to discrete systems is explained by having the system in space state representation. Ackerman among other methods are then explained because the system must be completely controllable to put the poles in any desired place in the unit circle.

My question here is if is completely necessary to transform the system to the space state representation to the make the calculations with those methods? Or can it be done by simply comparing the characteristic equations for the actual system and the desired system and then solving for the controller constants?

The question can be obvious to many people, but for me it doesn't since until now I couldn't find any other explanations apart from those shown in the Ogata book.

Comment: Converting from the s-domain to the z-domain via the bilinear transform is normally successful.

Comment: There are other methods transforming https://soar.wichita.edu/bitstream/handle/10057/1564/t07116.pdf?sequence=3

Comment: https://blog.mbedded.ninja/electronics/circuit-design/bldc-motor-control/

Comment: It's not part of your question, but -- consider using some form of robust control design method instead of pole placement.  Pole placement does _nothing_ to help you design a robust system -- the people I know who have done it successfully "just know" where to locate the poles for a system that works as it should.  For many SISO systems, designing for gain and phase margin is more than satisfactory, or, if you're inclined, you can use one of the modern robust control design methodologies.

Comment: @Chu what I did is precisely that, transform my plant to z-domain by bilinear method and then start from there using the zero order holder, just when I arrived to the part of the design of the controller by pole placement then I read in the book that apparently I need to discretize the equation of the part of the system that is in the direct trayectory

Comment: @Chu I mean, (controller plus zero order holder plus plant) and then evaluate the controlability of the system to calculate the feedback matrix, doing the transformation using bilinear method of the equations calculated in the s-domain was what worked wrong, that is why I started to read the pole placement design in discrete on the Ogata discret

Comment: @vram, You said that the s-plane version worked well, so a straight conversion to the z-plane via BLT should have done a similar job.

Answer (score 1):

For a single-input, single-output (SISO) system, converting to state space is unnecessary overkill.  If the system is SISO, and after you work out the transfer function of your system, it both has the same order in the denominator as the system has known states *and* it has no pole/zero cancellations, then it is both controllable and observable.

For a system that's either multi-input or multi-output, it can be more difficult to tell if it's observable and controllable -- in that case, you probably want to *start* with the system in state space and *keep* the system in state space.

Comment: thanks for your answer, look, when the transfer function of the zero order holder is added, a transport delay is aded in the direct trayectory, since I'm coding those equations in maxima then is extremelly posible that maxima couldn't give me de desired results so I used a Pade transformation of order 1 for the transport delay (also functions that comes with maxima), using Pade means that when the transfer functions of the direct trayectory are transformed using bilinear then a zero and a pole are added to my system so the order in the denominator is increased by one

Comment: then, it means that obligatorily do I need to transform my system to the state space and do all the remaining calculations from there?

Comment: SISO designs are suboptimal if they are dynamic with many outputs ignored that affect performance. Like da/dt=jerk torque, over-current, temp. rise, overshoot slow response. So not necessarily overkill!(-1)  Motor control can easily not be a SISO design if control ranges are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Z-plane optimization algorithms and acceptance criteria for all parameters of time, position, velocity and acceleration and you know how much margin you need inside the circle under all states, then go for it.

But if you don't have linear feedback for the state space parameter you need to control, you will have transform challenges or error overshoot issues.

I think that means current feedback for acceleration and some form of tachometer for RPM or velocity and shaft encoder if you want phase or position control. But it depends on your tolerance specs.

example paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/306944317_Design_of_a_Nonlinear_Fractional_Order_PID_Neural_Controller_for_Mobile_Robot_based_on_Particle_Swarm_Optimization

This means single sensor PID control systems are sub-optimal but can be adequate. (depends on tolerances) ** **Better control uses multiple sensors with more the better, as in PID feedback.**  Like acceleration, velocity and position (or a,v,x) feedback we have when driving a car. We feel "a", and can see v and x or read the dash for feedback from the speedometer and odometer or GPS.  Then we drive to null the error in desired goals for each a,v,x.... or just drive like crazy (lol).

** **This is regardless of whatever domain you want to control the design,** but will have cost-benefit tradeoffs.

**The biggest benefits for state current feedback in BLDC control are** reducing the dynamic range of current from >100 to 10:1 with constant  acceleration to target speed to match expected target load.  Reduction of dynamic error in demand current with changes in stalled rotor or inertia, faster detection/correction of load changes to speed. i.e greater BW .

*This holds true regardless of which domains are used for design control criteria. **The goal is to define good specs then achieve them by best practise** and be able to verify the results.*

Comment: Well, I'm controlling velocity but right now I don't have any of those parameters that you mentioned, I'm asking because right now I don't have enough knowledge of working ins the state space but obviously I can learn

Comment: That reveals some of your problems. If you do not sense current and regulate acceleration, you will suffer performance from integrating voltage with stability or over-current issues. This is what I mean by 1st order actually I think it is 0 order or same order as in proportional.  When the response is very slow, you can neglect this, like stepping on gas a known amount then read speedomter later is integration of velocity error unless you count sensation of acceleration as 0 order feedback.

Comment: Ok ok, now I understand what your saying, thats why I see in many designs that they measure current in addition to velocity and/or position, basically they're working in the state space representation and they need the parameters to work with.

Comment: I will see my calculations but I think that I'll need to learn state space representation to design my system.

Comment: In the meantime I'm going to take a while to answer because I need to analize what I've done to see what I'm going to do next thanks in advance for the help

Comment: We know from spectral response and Q and phase margin how state space response differs in Bessel vs Butterworth vs Chebychev etc. So there is good reason to know the group delay and Q effects on state space. Once learned it may be possible then to choose Z domain optimal locations  equivalent to time and frequency states

Comment: http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+5+50+5+50%0A%25+6+24389.095776063856%0Al+64+112+112+112+0+0.009647586263021712+0%0Ac+112+112+144+112+0+6.563894641624788e-7+0%0Ac+144+112+144+224+0+0.0000035307489350858867+0%0Al+192+112+192+224+0+0.0017935497805346133+0%0Aw+144+112+192+112+0%0Aw+192+112+240+112+0%0Ar+240+112+240+224+0+50%0Ag+144+224+144+240+0%0Ag+192+224+192+240+0%0Ag+240+224+240+240+0%0A170+64+112+32+112+2+20+4000+5+0.1%0AO+240+112+288+112+0%0AB+64+16+192+320+3+Box%0A

Comment: with above you can see experiment with different filters then display pole/zeros with phase, then copy schematic and paste in the other falstad circuit site and do a step response

Comment: @vram Basically, the BLDC motors are torque controlled. The current is mostly proportional to torque. And I don't know if current is measured in "most designs", because I have yet to see one that *doesn't* measure current. All the ones I saw did, unless they ran open-loop. And indeed, open loop is common. We call those things stepper motors - but they are indeed BLDC motors, just with many more electrical cycles per mechanical rotation.

Comment: Yes and the best noise immunity might use Hall Sensors with 3 phase with tight commutation accuracy.